# Cross Joined trigger on insert and update. Having issues matching rows and column from C#

Tags: sql-server, relational-database

I have Costumers table and Costumers_update table. I have created a trigger that Cross Joins the fields from Costumers table to Costumers_update table. I'm trying to match the rows and columns properly but I get mismatches all over the place when I do a SELECT query from C# on my winform.

The intentions of the query is to have some kind of log from Costumers previous information to the current which is why I have the trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerModify
ON Costumers AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Costumers_Update (
        CostumerID,
        ModifyDate,
        Name_New,   
        Email_New,      
        Name_Old,   
        Email_Old,  
        --etc
    )
    SELECT  [Old].ID,
            GETDATE(),
            [New].Name,
            [New].Email,
            [Old].Name,
            [Old].Email,
    FROM inserted AS [New]
    CROSS JOIN
    deleted AS [Old]
END
```

When I do a SELECT or SELECT DISTINCT I get everyhing mashed up.

The Costumers tables structur is almost the same as Costumers_update except the [OLD] fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "mismatches all over the place".

However, you are doing a `CROSS JOIN`, so you are getting every combination of "new" and "old" values across multiple records.

I would suggest that you use a simple `JOIN`:

```
FROM inserted [New] JOIN
     deleted [Old]
     [New].CustomerId = [Old].CustomerId
```

Comment: I mean that when I SELECT * FROM Costumers_Update ORDER by ModifyDate DESC, I get the mismatches. I want to eliminate the duplicates and match [New] and [Old] data row to row.

Comment: @chrstie . . . This version might help.  You probably have a bunch of garbage rows in the `Customers_Update` table.

Comment: Ok Thanks alot for the helping il try it out.